# Idris - Bowling scoring

Tags: idris

Having read the great [Type Driven Development in Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) book, I started fiddling with an implementation for a Bowling scoring system in Idris.

My initial goal was to model the score with types and [make illegal states unrepresentable](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-making-illegal-states-unrepresentable/), which I think I succeeded to do so. Following is the snippet showing `GameScore` type for a [Ten-pin Bowling game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten-pin_bowling#Scoring):

```
import Data.Fin
import Data.Vect

%default total

data Frame : Type where
     Strike : Frame
     Spare : (first : Fin 10) -> Frame
     Pins : (first : Nat) -> 
            (second : Nat) ->
            {auto prf : LT (first + second) 10} -> 
            Frame

bonus : Frame -> Type
bonus Strike = (Fin 11, Fin 11)
bonus (Spare _) = (Fin 11)
bonus (Pins _ _) = ()

FrameAndBonus : Type
FrameAndBonus = (frame : Frame ** bonus frame)

data GameScore : Type where 
  MkGameScore : Vect 9 Frame -> FrameAndBonus -> GameScore

sampleGame : GameScore
sampleGame = MkGameScore 
          ([Strike, Pins 2 7, Spare 2, Strike, Strike,
            Strike, Spare 9,  Strike,  Strike])
          (Strike ** (9, 8))
```

I'm quite happy with this first part, but of course  any feedback is always welcome.

What I struggled more with however, was implementing a function to count the actual score (with `Nat` type):

```
score : FrameAndBonus -> Nat
score (Strike ** (b1, b2)) = 10 + finToNat b1 + finToNat b2
score ((Spare _) ** b1) = 10 + finToNat b1
score ((Pins first second) ** ()) = first + second

throws : Frame -> Type
throws Strike = Fin 11
throws _ = (Fin 11, Fin 11)

throwsHelp : (frame : Frame) -> throws frame
throwsHelp Strike = 10
throwsHelp (Spare first) = 
  (weaken first, restrict 10 (10 - finToInteger first))
throwsHelp (Pins first second) =
  (restrict 10 (toIntegerNat first), restrict 10 (toIntegerNat second))

firstThrow : Frame -> Fin 11
firstThrow Strike = throwsHelp Strike
firstThrow (Spare first) = fst $ throwsHelp (Spare first)
firstThrow (Pins first second) = fst $ throwsHelp (Pins first second)

twoThrows : (f1 : Frame ** throws f1) -> 
            (f2 : Frame ** throws f2) -> 
            (Fin 11, Fin 11)
twoThrows (Strike ** t1) (Strike ** t2) = (t1, t2)
twoThrows (Strike ** t1) (Spare _ ** (t2,_)) = (t1, t2)
twoThrows (Strike ** t1) (Pins _ _ ** (t2,_)) = (t1, t2)
twoThrows (Spare _ ** (t1,t2)) _ = (t1,t2)
twoThrows (Pins _ _ ** (t1,t2)) _ = (t1,t2)

initBonus : (current : Frame) ->
            (next : Frame) ->
            (third : Frame) ->
            bonus current
initBonus Strike next third = 
  twoThrows (next ** throwsHelp next) (third ** throwsHelp third)
initBonus (Spare _) next _ = firstThrow next
initBonus (Pins _ _) _ _ = ()

twoBonus : (frame : Frame) -> 
           throws frame ->
           bonus frame -> 
           (Fin 11, Fin 11)
twoBonus Strike t1 (t2,_) = (t1,t2)
twoBonus (Spare _) (t1,t2) _ = (t1,t2)
twoBonus (Pins _ _) (t1,t2) _ = (t1,t2)

ninthBonus : (ninth : Frame) -> 
             (tenth : Frame) -> 
             bonus tenth -> 
             bonus ninth
ninthBonus Strike tenth tenthBonus =
   twoBonus tenth (throwsHelp tenth) tenthBonus
ninthBonus (Spare _) tenth _ = firstThrow tenth
ninthBonus (Pins _ _) _ _ = ()

vectCommutative : Vect (m + n) elem -> Vect (n + m) elem
vectCommutative {m} {n} xs = rewrite sym (plusCommutative m n) in xs

triplewise : Vect (2 + n) elem -> Vect n (elem, elem, elem)
triplewise {n} xs = zip3 first second third where
  first  = take n $ vectCommutative xs
  second = let (_ :: tail) = xs in init tail
  third  = drop 2 xs

frames : GameScore -> Vect 10 FrameAndBonus
frames (MkGameScore frames (tenth ** tenthBonus)) = 
  map (\(f1,f2,f3) => (f1 ** initBonus f1 f2 f3))
      (triplewise (frames ++ [tenth])) 
  ++ rest
where
  ninth : Frame 
  ninth = last frames
  ninthB : bonus ninth
  ninthB = ninthBonus ninth tenth tenthBonus
  rest = [(ninth ** ninthB), (tenth ** tenthBonus)]

points : GameScore -> Nat
points = sum . map score . frames

main : IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ points sampleGame
```

This code works, but there's a number of issues I'm not fully satisfied with, and would be grateful for some guidance:

1. In order to minimize code repetition, I tried to create create a view `FrameThrows` over `Frame` type with two possible cases `OneThrow` and `TwoThrows`. I failed to implement the view however, mainly because I wasn't able to define a covering function for the `TwoThrows` case. How could this view be defined? Following mapping should apply:

   - `Strike` -> `OneThrow` with 10 pins,
   - `Spare x` -> `TwoThrows x (10-x)`,
   - `Pins x y` -> `TwoThrows x y`.
2. I had hard times dealing with `Fin` vs `Nat` types. Ideally, `points` function could be of type `GameScore -> Fin 301` to restrict the maximum score to 300 points, but then I [found that](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/Fin.idr#L8-L9) "*It's probably not a good idea to use `Fin` for arithmetic, and they will be exceedingly inefficient at run time.*" `Fin` turned out helpful to model `Spare` case as well as `bonus` and `throws` though. What's your take on this? Is it ok to use `Fin` for counting the score up to 300? How would you do this?
3. While implementing `triplewise` function, I needed to create a helper function `vectCommutative` to make the compiler happy. Is there an easier and more concise way (built-in functions?) to create triplets from a vector?

Looking for some feedback regarding the above questions, as well as any other issues spotted in the code above.

Comment: FWIW I recently found a much better implementation of the very same problem: https://deque.blog/2017/07/01/idris-bowling-kata/